# Debug android shared library interactivly

Tags: android

I have been trying to reverse engineer .so file in android application.I used objdump from android ndk to look at the assembly of the file.I do not have a problem with assembly but analyzing the file statically is just so tedious.I am looking for a method to actually run the application on my phone and set break points and see how the registers and the stack are updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford the paid version of IDA Pro, this is very easy:

- make sure your Windows, Linux or OSX Host is in the same network as your phone via WIFI
- start `android_server` on your phone
- use any tool to find out the WIFI ip of the phone
- after starting the application on your phone, load the .so in IDA, start the remote debugger, and connect to the IP you found out in step 3